# Passing Data from 1 view Controller to another

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried to use many other strategies but as of yet, have not succeeded.

I've made a true or false game. If you get the answer right, your score increases by one point. If you get it wrong, you're sent through to a GameOver View Controller.

What I'm trying to do is to have the Score you got, transfer from the SecondVC to the GameOverVC.

```
var Score = 0

if AnswerNumber == 0 {
    Score += 1
    Score_Keeper.text = NSString(format:"%i",Score) as String
```

(Score_Keeper is the name of my label which shows you your current Score on SecondVC)

```
else {

     let destinationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdVC")
     presentViewController(destinationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This brings me to my GameOverVC. To assign the "Score" to my UILabel in the GameOver Screen I have written at the very end of my code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let SecondVC: GameOver = segue.destinationViewController as! GameOver

    SecondVC.LabelText == Score
```

LabelText in my GameOverVC is

```
var LabelText = Int()
```

And in my View Did Load I've written:

```
Score_Number.text = "\(LabelText)"
```

Where Score_Number is the name of my UILabel. Basically, I want my Score_Number in GameOverVC to = Score in the Second VC.

I hope my question is clear... Thank you so much!!

Comment: I encourage you to not capitalise property names, it's considered bad practice. :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to implement prepareForSegue. Just assign the value before presenting it

```
 let destinationController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdVC") as GameOverVC
 destinationController.LabelText = score;
 presentViewController(desinationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also in your prepareforSegue assignment should

```
SecondVC.LabelText = Score
```

instead of

```
SecondVC.LabelText == Score
```

Comment: It gives me a "Use of Unresolved identifier 'destinationController'" error. I'm new to all this, so what does that mean? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: There's a typo, it says `desinationController` on the first line.

Comment: just copied it from snippet in the question. Now updated it. @MatteoSquire it is the variable of type GameOverVC class.

Comment: Oops sorry, I changed that and now the error is, "Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'LabelText'"

Comment: updated the first line of code. Also "ThirdVC" is for GameOverVC. Right?